# Black Scholes PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

How to show that $V_1(S,t)=S\frac{\partial V(S,t)}{\partial S} $ satisfies Black-Scholes PDE given as $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} + rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} -rV = 0$ ?

Comment: I have tried to differentiate $V_1(S,t)$ and plug it in the Black-Scholes PDE, but could not produce the required relation. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that $V_1(S,t)=S\frac{\partial V(S,t)}{\partial S}$ satisfies equation?

Comment: Well, I do not think, I just want to prove it. The original question is: Given that $V(S,t)$, the solution of PDE mentioned above, is infinitely differentiable in $S>0$ and $t<T$, show that $V_1(S,t)=S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}(S,t)$ also satisfies the Black-Scholes PDE.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V(S,t)$ --- solution of the PDE.
Then 
$$
S\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} + rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} -rV\right) = 0
$$
$$
S\left(\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial t \partial S} + \frac{\sigma^2 }{2}\left(2S\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} + S^2\frac{\partial^3V}{\partial S^3}\right) + r\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + rS\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} - r\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2 }{2}\left(2\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} + S\frac{\partial^3V}{\partial S^3}\right) + rS^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} = 0.
$$
Here we note that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right) = 2\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} + S\frac{\partial^3V}{\partial S^3}$
and $rS\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right) = 
rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + rS^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}$.

And finally 
$$
\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2V_1}{\partial S^2} + rS\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial S} -rV_1 = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there any underlying idea for the first line?

Comment: Also, for this given problem, there is a boundary condition $V(S,T)=f(S)$. Is it possible to check that derived PDE also satisfies boundary condition?

Comment: The idea is "try and error". You also should change boundary condition: $V_1(S,T) = SV'_S(S,T) = Sf'(S)$

Comment: Thank you for your help. The second part of the question was to show that $\rho(S,t) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}(S,t)$ satisfies the following PDE:

$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial S^2} +rS\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial S} - r\rho = V - S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$, which I have done by following your way from the first part.

Comment: Then the question is: given that the PDE above uniquely determines $\rho$, and assuming that both $V$ and $S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$ are of the order $o(1/(T-t))$ as $t \to T^-$, show that $\rho(S,t) = (T-t)\Big(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}(S,t) - V(s,t)\Big)$.

Comment: It would be better to formulate the second part as another question (not in comments). It is kind a rule of this site.

Comment: Thank for your work Nikita. I also separated second part of the question. please find "interesting boundary problem of PDE "